# Generating the string correspondent to the passwd command

Tags: passwords, password-recovery, passwd

I have a protected page on my server and I forgot the password to that page. Ok, I can change that password but it will be a hassle because I have that password stored in a lot of systems that use them to access the directory. I can see the .passwords file, something like

myusername:$aprX8XYAJG.../O5E1

Is there a command on unix I can use to generate that mumbo jumbo string to terminal, so I can compare both and see if I have a match?

I mean generate to a file without interfering or creating new users or passwords in the system.

Comment: If the "jumbo jumbo string" is a hash then it cannot be reversed.  We need more information about how the password is stored in those systems.  Be specific and update your question.  Depending on the length of the password, instead of trying to reverse a secured password hash function, a brute force attack would be appropriate.

Comment: I am not trying to reverse. I know a lot of passwords that can be the one in the system. I want to generate the password string from these passwords I know and then compare both generated strings.

Comment: So what encryption algorithm or hashing function was used to generate the  "mumbo jumbo string"?  its your system there are to many possibilities for us to simply guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan to compare the hash across several systems may or may not produce the result you want, based on the origin of the hash on each system.

Hashes are the output of a [one-way mapping function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) that will always (in theory) produce the same result for an given input, and will not produce that same string for any other input. The issue is that there are many many hash algorithms, [and some alter the input in a predictable manner before hashing (called "Salting the Hash")](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). Others use a variable number of "rounds" where the resultant hash is rehashed multiple times.

If the hashes were created with the same hash algorithm, and no machine-specific salt was used, then both systems would generate the same hash for the same password, and your plan will work.

If however, the mechanism to generate the hashes on each box are different, or they include a system-specific token for salt, then no, the same password would generate a different hash output on each system, so you could be looking at two different hashes and not know whether they were based on the same password input.

See here for details about how the linux PAM uses hashing in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SHA_password_hashes